# Libgdx - How to make the dialog fade but not the whole stage?

Tags: dialog, libgdx, fadein, stage

When I show a Dialog with

```
someDialog.show(someStage);
```

The dialog show with default FadeIn action.
And the stage fade in too. So it make my background fade along with the stage.

How can I prevent this to happen?

Edit:
Here my example code:

In Screen show method:

```
Texture bg = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(src));
stage = new Stage(game.getViewport(), batch);
stage.addActor(someDialog) //just normal dialog
```

render code:

```
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        super.render(delta);
        getBatch().begin();
        getBatch().draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0, width, height);
        getBatch().end();
        getStage().act(delta);
        getStage().draw();
        time += delta;
    }
```

I show the dialog when some event trigger:

```
   dialog.show(getStage());
```

I have tried to put null as second parameter to the show method

```
dialog.show(getStage(), null);
```

and make both stage and dialog not fade in but a want to keep the effect for only dialog or at least not the background.

Comment: where is your stage.act() and stage.draw()

Comment: Is that "render code" you showed the `draw` method of your stage? Because you should not really be overriding the method. Your drawing code should be in the dialog's `draw` method.

Comment: @Fish they are in screen's render method

Comment: @StrongJoshua Dialog have no draw or render method. you have to use dialog.show(stage)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stage doesn't clean up the SpriteBatch's color when it's done, so when the loop comes back around, the last-used color is still applied to the sprite batch. In your case, the last used color happens to be the dialog's color.

To fix this, add `getBatch().setColor(Color.WHITE);` before your `getBatch().draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0, width, height);` line.

And I don't think your whole stage is fading. Right now, your background texture has nothing to do with the stage, except that they're both sharing use of the SpriteBatch.

Comment: you're my life saver. I'm actually use the same SpriteBatch for both but your answer worked.

Comment: Yes, they should share a sprite batch. It's a waste of memory to have more than one instance of SpriteBatch. You just need to clean up after it sometimes.

Comment: Is it a known issue? At least they should instruct newbies to color the stage each round .... A strange requirement to start with...

Comment: @rubmz It is explained here in the Drawing section: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d It is not an "issue". It is designed this way because it is a game framework so the redundancy of changing the batch back to white after every actor is drawn must be avoided.

Comment: It is a very strange behaviour, and a very strange requirement that any drawable object need to re-set the color to white after each draw... I do understand that there is an optimization here, but this is a major pain-in-the-ass to just understand from the whole thing written above what to do in order to cause your scene not to fade out?! Nice to know it is fixable, but it IS an issue. At least poor documentation. For new libgdx users - this is a major drive away (escuse my english :) )

Comment: @rubmz I agree it's not at all intuitive, and I see that it is not mentioned in the actual Javadoc, only on the wiki instructions. Maybe I'll make a PR to improve it later.